# Изменение вида вывода времени

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
 ZoneId Syd = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");
    ZoneId los = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");

    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 11, 11, 11, 15);
    LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 11, 11, 6, 0);

    ZonedDateTime SydDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, Syd);
    ZonedDateTime losDateTime2 = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime2, los);

    Duration duration = Duration.between(SydDateTime, losDateTime2);

    System.out.println(duration);
```

**Вывод** выглядит вот так: **PT13H45M**

**Проблема**: хочу сделать вывод более удобным для чтения, пытался использовать formatter, но постоянно выкидывает exception.

**Вопрос**: каким образом возможно вывести используя formatter?

Comment: У Duration есть много методов для преобразования полученного тобой значения. Например, чтобы вывести это в дни используй метод `duration.toDays()`, а в миллисекунды - `duration.toMillis()` и т.п.

Comment: А вообще вот тебе отличный сайт, где в конце списка будет краткий экскурс по java.time:
[Java 8 New Date / Time API](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-8-uchebnik/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать человеко-читаемый вид, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266846/5909792):

```
public static String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
    long absSeconds = Math.abs(seconds);
    String positive = String.format(
        "%d:%02d:%02d",
        absSeconds / 3600,
        (absSeconds % 3600) / 60,
        absSeconds % 60);
    return seconds < 0 ? "-" + positive : positive;
}
```

использование:

```
...
Duration duration = Duration.between(SydDateTime, losDateTime2);
System.out.println(duration);
// PT13H45M

System.out.println(formatDuration(duration));
// 13:45:00
```